# unit testing of many simple *ngIf

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, angular-test

I have simply component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-certificate-panel',
    templateUrl: './certificate.component.html'
})
export class CertificateComponent {
    @Input()
    public certificate: Certificate;
}
```

with template

```
<h3 translate>General</h3>
<x-form-row label="{{'Version' | translate}}">
    {{ certificate.version }}
</x-form-row>
<x-form-row label="{{'Serial Number' | translate}}">
    {{ certificate.serialNumber }}
</x-form-row>
<h3 translate>Issued From</h3>
<x-form-row label="{{'Common Name (CN)' | translate}}" *ngIf="certificate.issuedFrom.commonName">
    {{ certificate.issuedFrom.commonName }}
</x-form-row>
<x-form-row label="{{'Organization Unit (OU)' | translate}}" *ngIf="certificate.issuedFrom.organizationUnit">
    {{ certificate.issuedFrom.organizationUnit }}
</x-form-row>
```

There are more properties shown. There are several `*ngIf` in this template.

Now I want to write unit tests. Should I test each `*ngIf`? Isn't it testing the framework functionality?

Comment: where the input to the `*ngIf` comes from?

Comment: Personally I would unit test this piece of code. There is no real gain in unit test simple ifs (ngIfs) in the template layer. I usually keep unit test form my components/services/etc... and not templates, and the template logic is testes within e2e tests.

Comment: @Aravind it is `@Input` set in parent component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a range of possible tests you could do with this component:

1. setup compoenent then query DOM elements to ensure they are present, personally, I don't do these if `ngIf`s but if it's critial then you have to make the call, it's your app.
2. since `ngIf` checks the truthy-ness of the statement, unit test the statement, ie: setup component, check truthy-ness of all those statements. Again, depending on the context, since this is getting data from a parent, you should think about how sure you are that this is going to be populated, program defensively. If there is a chance it could break, just do a cheap test like this.
3. it's sometimes pointless to test `ngIf`, like I said in 2, this might be a waste of time since it's going to either be truthy or not so if you can control for that then this component is very simple.
4. Also you could make a parent test component in the spec to do an integration test, this is very involved but if this component tree is critical or complex, this is often very robust test (Personally would rarely do these).

The good thing about your component above is that it's simple, and therefore the tests can be simple. I would personally do option 2